# Why does reinstantiating an object delete any references other objects may have had to it?

Tags: c#, generics, reference

I made a generic class that holds a simple object (PassedObject) which just contains an integer. To understand where my container loses its reference to my initial 'PassedObject' instance, i printed the data after simply changing the number field and again after making a new instance of b.

```
PassedObject b = new PassedObject(20);
ObjectHolder<PassedObject> objectHolder = new ObjectHolder<PassedObject>(b);

objectHolder.PrintData(); // prints 20
b.number = 888;
objectHolder.PrintData(); // prints 888
b = new PassedObject(7782);
objectHolder.PrintData(); // prints 888
b.number = 2;
objectHolder.PrintData(); // still 888, lost reference...

public class PassedObject
{
    public int number { get; set; }

    public PassedObject(int number)
    {
        this.number = number;
    }
}

public class ObjectHolder<T> where T : PassedObject
{
    public T passedObject;

    public ObjectHolder(T newObject)
    {
        passedObject = newObject;
    }

    public void PrintData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(passedObject.number);
    }
}
```

My question is: Given that my objectHolder still points to the same variable (b), why do I lose that reference to b after reconstructing it?

Comment: You're referencing the original through `b` but the holder has a different reference `passedObject` to the same object. Changing `b` doesn't change what the holder is pointing to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the question has **two `PassedObject` references**: one in the `b` variable, and one in the `objectHolder.PassedObject` variable.

Initially, the code creates a new `PassedObject` instance and assigns it to the `b` reference. Then the `b` reference is used to also set the `objectHolder.PassedObject`.

At this point, both references refer to the *same object instance*, but they are still two different variables. Because they refer to the same object, we can update **properties** via one reference and we will see the change in the other. This is why the change to `888` works.

However, updating a property is not the same as replacing the reference itself. The next thing the code does is create brand new `PassedObject` instance and assign it to the `b` reference. This assignment does **not** also update `objectHolder.PassedObject`.

As this point the two references *no longer refer to the same object*. The `objectHolder.PassedObject` variable continues to refer to the prior `888` instance. Since it is a completely different reference, updating the `.number` property via the `b` reference won't change anything.